# Looking for a drawing app that allows multiple iPads to simultaneously/collaboratively draw on the same file

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, appletv

I am looking for an iPad app which allows multiple iPad users to draw to the same screen/page simultaneously so that the result is displayed on a monitor, possibly via Apple TV.

We intend to use this for user experience (design) work, so ideally it would have Text and Rectangle drawing. Snapping would also be nice.

Does anyone have any suggestions on an app or another approach we could use to achieve this?

Comment: What app or apps have you found that meet some of your needs, but fail at others?

Comment: None that I can see. I want multiple people to be able to draw on iPads simultaneously. Any apps that present only let one person do it. Also wants basic drawing tools like rectangles, preferably with text inside since most of the work will be for user experience.